# Story Identification: Carnivorous Pack-Hunting Chipmunks

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, biology

I recall reading a short story back in the 80's that featured some biologists who ran across a pack of carnivorous chipmunks in a national park.

They would gang-up on larger creatures, like owls, and devour them. At the book they drop from a tree and attack one of the main characters. It seems like he survives.

I am not certain where I would have read it, but it seems like it was in a school textbook.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's called *[Evolution Never Sleeps](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?84521)*, by [Elisabeth Malartre](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?17768), and it was first published in *Asimov's* in 1999, and later published in David Hartwell's anthology, [*The Year's Best SF 5*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0061020540) (where I read it).  A plot summary is available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20060206194616/https://archonrealm.tripod.com/reviews/evolutionneversleeps.htm) which matches your memory of the story.

> **Evolution Never Sleeps** by Elisabeth Malartre. Another one with a connection to the preceding story. Like the last story, this one features a glaringly obvious thing on page 5 that no one notices.
>
> Basically, this remote mountain area (where some scientists are working) evolves a pack of carnivorous nocturnal chipmunks. Fine, but then two people reach the conclusion that the chipmunks will soon start attacking live prey instead of carrion, and then these same two people (who are supposed to be scientists - high IQ does not mean common sense) go out the next night right into the chipmunks' turf looking for a certain owl.
>
> The major surprise of this piece is that they got out alive, though the owl didn't. (Pretty amazing chipmunks, being able to down owls, who presumably could fly away before being overwhelmed.)
>
> At least it didn't end with the chipmunks taking over the world, like I half expected.

Comment: I was also able to find the story online fairly easily, but I'm not sure if it's a legal copy of the text, so I won't post the link.

Comment: That does sound like it, but I could have sworn I had read it before 1999. I suppose that everything before the turn of the century blurs together now...